# How to append text from label to other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

I have this markup:

```
<span class="top_ticker_middle"></span>
<div class="pc_elements">
  <fieldset class="checkable">
    <span class="as_cp_checkbox"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="pc_element_01" id="pc_element_01" value="yes">
    <label for="pc_element_01">Some text</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

now: i need to append text from label to `top_ticker_middle` span after some click. I have many of this fieldsets in the list, and i should do this for specify, clicked element. Also i need to append this values one by one in the span `top_ticker_middle`. So i do this:

```
$('.pc_elements fieldset').live('click',function(){
    var text_label = $(this).children('label').text();
    $('.top_ticker_middle').empty().append(text_label);
});
```

something is wrong and not working, can you help me?

Comment: Can a FIELDSET capture events? Why not bind the click to the pc_elements DIV?

Comment: User appendTo instead of append!

Comment: this not chanking anything, now i have only empty span

Comment: Works fine for me (but you shouldn't be using `.live()`) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7p6A/)

Comment: OFFTOPIC `$('.top_ticker_middle').empty().append(text_label);` can also be `$('.top_ticker_middle').html(text_label);`

Comment: Original code works for me. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAZnT/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Replace:

```
var text_label = $(this).children('label').text();
$('.top_ticker_middle').empty().append(text_label);
```

#### With:

```
var text_label = $(this).find('label').text();
$('.top_ticker_middle').html($('.top_ticker_middle').html() + text_label);
```

I faced the same issue! :)

#### Original Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bAZnT/ (Actually this works!)

Comment: ok, it's working, but now how can i add this one by one, value by velue - click add value, click add value, not changing it?

Comment: I don't get you. One by one, what?

Comment: You need to append it, is it?

Comment: i have multipple of this fieldsets, and labels, after click on one of it it's appending text from label to my span, but if i click at the next fieldset, previous is deleting and appending the new one, i need to add one by one smthg like that: value, value, value, value

Comment: Try this: `$('.top_ticker_middle').html($('.top_ticker_middle').html() + text_label);`. Updated in the answer too! :)

Comment: ok, it's working but now i have multiplies the elements, so: velue1velue1, velue2velue2 ...

Comment: In that case, you give the label to append, a class, something like, `<label class="append">` and change the javascript this way: `$(this).find('label.append').text();`

Comment: i can't add class for labels becouse it will be generated by php, so i dont know how many it would be

Comment: OKay, give this way. `$(this).find('label').first().text();`

Comment: good but still i have this issue where elements are multiplied

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest finding the span by dom tree structure :

```
$('.pc_elements fieldset').live('click',function(){
    var text_label = $(this).children('label').text();
    $(this).parent().find('.top_ticker_middle').empty().append(text_label);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pc_elements fieldset').live('click',function(){
        var text_label = $(this).children('label').text();
        $(this).parent().prev('.top_ticker_middle').empty().append(text_label);
    });
});​
```